In python 3.12 and kivymd2.0.1 change backgroundcolor in the topappbar
I have tried this in both the kvfile and in the python code. I am using themes and try to change the backgroundcolor to either white or black depending on theme style dark or light.
In the kvfile it messes up all of the themecolors and in the python code nothing happens at all.
I have built a small app which allows you to set a theme and dark or light. A button leads you to a new screen where the topappbar is. You hav to install kivymd 2.0.1(dev0) to be able to run the app.
pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip)
palette.kv
WindowManager:
    MainScreen
    NextScreen

<MainScreen>
    name: "mainscreen"
    theme: current_theme
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.backgroundColor

    MDFloatLayout:
        MDTextField:
            id: current_theme
            disabled: True
            multiline: False
            size_hint_x: .4
            on_text: root.current_theme = self.text
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.8}
            MDTextFieldHintText:
                text: "Current Theme"

        MDTextField:
            id: counter_field
            disabled: True
            multiline: False
            size_hint_x: .1
            on_text: root.counter = self.text
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.7}
            MDTextFieldHintText:
                text: "Counter"


        MDLabel:
            pos_hint: {'x': .6, 'center_y': 0.9}
            font_style: "Label"
            text: "Dark or light"

        MDSwitch:
            id: theme_switch
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .6, 'center_y': .8}
            on_active: root.toggle_theme(self.active)
             # 'self.active' returnerar True om switchen är aktiverad, annars False

        MDButton:
            style: "outlined"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.4, "center_y": 0.15}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            on_press:
                root.goto_back()
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Back"

        MDButton:
            style: "outlined"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": 0.15}  # Adjust y position to be below the ScrollView
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            on_press:
                root.goto_forward()

            MDButtonText:
                text: "Forward"

        MDButton:
            style: "outlined"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": 0.15}  # Adjust y position to be below the ScrollView
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            on_press:
                root.goto_next_screen()

            MDButtonText:
                text: "Next Window"

<NextScreen>
    name: "nextscreen"

    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.backgroundColor


    MDTopAppBar:
        id: topappbar
        type: "small"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.9}


        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer:
            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                icon: "arrow-left"
                on_press: root.goto_main_screen()

        MDTopAppBarTitle:
            text: "TopAppBar"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}



from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

palette = [
    'Aliceblue', 'Antiquewhite', 'Aqua', 'Aquamarine', 'Azure', 'Beige', 'Bisque', 'Black', 'Blanchedalmond',
    'Blue', 'Blueviolet', 'Brown', 'Burlywood', 'Cadetblue', 'Chartreuse', 'Chocolate', 'Coral',
    'Cornflowerblue', 'Cornsilk', 'Crimson', 'Cyan', 'Darkblue', 'Darkcyan', 'Darkgoldenrod', 'Darkgray',
    'Darkgrey', 'Darkgreen', 'Darkkhaki', 'Darkmagenta', 'Darkolivegreen', 'Darkorange', 'Darkorchid',
    'Darkred', 'Darksalmon', 'Darkseagreen', 'Darkslateblue', 'Darkslategray', 'Darkslategrey',
    'Darkturquoise', 'Darkviolet', 'Deeppink', 'Deepskyblue', 'Dimgray', 'Dimgrey', 'Dodgerblue',
    'Firebrick', 'Floralwhite', 'Forestgreen', 'Fuchsia', 'Gainsboro', 'Ghostwhite', 'Gold', 'Goldenrod',
    'Gray', 'Grey', 'Green', 'Greenyellow', 'Honeydew', 'Hotpink', 'Indianred', 'Indigo', 'Ivory', 'Khaki',
    'Lavender', 'Lavenderblush', 'Lawngreen', 'Lemonchiffon', 'Lightblue', 'Lightcoral', 'Lightcyan',
    'Lightgoldenrodyellow', 'Lightgreen', 'Lightgray', 'Lightgrey', 'Lightpink', 'Lightsalmon',
    'Lightseagreen', 'Lightskyblue', 'Lightslategray', 'Lightslategrey', 'Lightsteelblue', 'Lightyellow',
    'Lime', 'Limegreen', 'Linen', 'Magenta', 'Maroon', 'Mediumaquamarine', 'Mediumblue', 'Mediumorchid',
    'Mediumpurple', 'Mediumseagreen', 'Mediumslateblue', 'Mediumspringgreen', 'Mediumturquoise',
    'Mediumvioletred', 'Midnightblue', 'Mintcream', 'Mistyrose', 'Moccasin', 'Navajowhite', 'Navy',
    'Oldlace', 'Olive', 'Olivedrab', 'Orange', 'Orangered', 'Orchid', 'Palegoldenrod', 'Palegreen',
    'Paleturquoise', 'Palevioletred', 'Papayawhip', 'Peachpuff', 'Peru', 'Pink', 'Plum', 'Powderblue',
    'Purple', 'Red', 'Rosybrown', 'Royalblue', 'Saddlebrown', 'Salmon', 'Sandybrown', 'Seagreen',
    'Seashell', 'Sienna', 'Silver', 'Skyblue', 'Slateblue', 'Slategray', 'Slategrey', 'Snow',
    'Springgreen', 'Steelblue', 'Tan', 'Teal', 'Thistle', 'Tomato', 'Turquoise', 'Violet', 'Wheat',
    'White', 'Whitesmoke', 'Yellow', 'Yellowgreen'
]

class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    current_theme = StringProperty("")
    counter = NumericProperty(0)
    darkorlight = "Light"

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = palette[0]
        self.current_theme = self.theme_cls.primary_palette
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_ids_current_theme, 0)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_ids_counter, 0)
        #self.set_ids_counter()

    def set_ids_current_theme(self, *args):
        if 'current_theme' in self.ids:
            self.ids.current_theme.text = self.current_theme
        else:
            print("current_theme ID not found.")


    def set_ids_counter(self, *args):
        self.ids.counter_field.text = str(self.counter)


    def goto_forward(self):
        if self.counter  < 146:
            self.counter = self.counter + 1
            self.set_palette()
            self.set_ids_current_theme()
            self.set_ids_counter()


    def goto_back(self):
        if self.counter  > 0:
            self.counter = self.counter - 1
            self.set_palette()
            self.set_ids_current_theme()
            self.set_ids_counter()

    def toggle_theme(self, is_active):
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.apply_theme(is_active), 0.3)

    def apply_theme(self, is_active):
        # Växlar mellan 'Dark' och 'Light' tema baserat på switchens läge
        if is_active:
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        else:
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

    def set_palette(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = palette[self.counter]
        self.current_theme = self.theme_cls.primary_palette


    def goto_next_screen(self):
        next_screen = self.manager.get_screen("nextscreen")  # Hämta referens till NewSiteScreen
        self.manager.current = "nextscreen"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"

class NextScreen(MDScreen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        print("on start")
        # Vänta tills gränssnittet är färdiginitierat innan färger sätts
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_appbar_color, 0.1)


    def set_appbar_color(self, *args):
        # Get set theme
        style = self.theme_cls.theme_style

        # Set backgroundcolor for topappbar
        if style == "Dark":
            self.ids.topappbar.md_bg_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]# White background
            self.ids.topappbar.specific_text_color = [0, 0, 0, 1]  # Black text
        else:
            # Style == "Light
            self.ids.topappbar.md_bg_color = [0, 0, 0, 1]  # Black background
            self.ids.topappbar.specific_text_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]# White text
        print(
            f"Theme Style: {style}, AppBar BG: {self.ids.topappbar.md_bg_color}, Text: {self.ids.topappbar.specific_text_color}")


    def goto_main_screen(self):
        main_screen = self.manager.get_screen("mainscreen")

        self.manager.current = "mainscreen"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"


class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass


class Palette(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.borderless = False



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Palette().run()


        id: topappbar
        type: "small"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.9}


        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer:
            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                icon: "arrow-left"
                on_press: root.goto_main_screen()

        MDTopAppBarTitle:
            text: "TopAppBar"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

